# Calling model.fit on target array of columns vs array of rows with separate output nodes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

The two *should* be equivalent in terms of how they are fed into the model or one should be accepted and the other incompatible. A list of columns vs a list of rows. My model architecture takes 5 inputs and spits out 3 outputs. I noticed that in training - when my target data was a 3 x 1000 numpy array I had losses in the region of 0.3 (which is unusually high considering when I predict on the test set my loss is 0.01). Often the loss at each output node is similar when using the standard columns and then differs greatly when using the rows.

Then transposing it `y.T` does not work - only when converting to a list `list(y.T)` does the model accept it as a target. Then the losses are much more comparable to what is expected. I know this should not work and passing in the columns should be the way to go - but why is my loss so much lower.

I know it sounds nonsensical but heres an MRE to validate whats happening:

```
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation="relu")(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation="relu")(x)
    out1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
    out2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
    out3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

    outputs = [out1, out2, out3]
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    # Creating data
    data = np.random.random(size=(300,8))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.columns = ["A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
    df["F"] = df["F"] * 2 # Perturbing 
    df["G"] = df["G"] * 3
    df["H"] = df["H"] * 4   
    model.compile(loss="mae")
    X = df[["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]]
    y = df[["F", "G", "H"]]
    ny = y.to_numpy()

    # history = model.fit(X, list(ny.T), epochs=200) # Alternate - uncomment when you want to use
    history = model.fit(X, ny, epochs=200) # standard
    pred = model.predict(X)
    pred = np.concatenate(pred, axis=1)
    resid = np.mean(np.abs(ny - pred), axis=0)
    print(resid) # Training loss is lower for rows...
```

Any help is appreciated. Maybe defining the model with separate output branches as opposed to a single `Dense(3)` changes things?

Comment: Well, in your example you can't predict random from random (garbage in, garbage out) i would suggest making FGH a FUNCTION OF abcdE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the output shape of your model. The way you have your output configured the shape is `[(None, 1), (None, 1), (None, 1)]`, so it expects a list of values, each of size `(None,1)`.If you use `Dense(3)` or `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(outputs)` then it has size  (None, 3) and that is what it expects. you can inspect the shape of your output using `model.output_shape`.

Comment: Ahhhhh I see, thank you very very much. The reason I used that architecture was to see the loss per output neuron. Is there a way to do it other than above?

Comment: hmmm, you can customize what happens during fit using callbacks (e.g. particular printouts). see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_your_own_callbacks

Comment: If I tried to pass a ```validation_split``` parameter whilst doing this i.e. the training data is a list of lists as mentioned - will keras incorrectly try to split the data?I noticed a significant difference between when I pass my own validation data and when letting keras do it.